# Type mismatch error in using scipy.optimize.brute for a ported c++ function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to use [scipy.optimize.brute](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brute.html) for a c++ function `func_cpp` of type `double -> double` that I have successfully ported to python.

Because `scipy.optimize.brute' only accepts functions over numpy arrays (see screenshot below for details on its interface), if I understand correctly I need to wrap my func_cpp to a python-callable function over 1-D numpy array. So I use:

```
def: func_cpp_array (arr):
   return np.array(map (func_cpp, arr.tolist())
```

The construct above is certainly awkward (any suggestion for a less clumsy one?). Still, it should return a callable function that can be accepted by `scipy.optimize.brute`.  Yet I get a type-mismatch error

```
TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration
```

when I use

```
ranges=slice(0,1,10)
scipy.optimize.brute (func_app_array, (ranges,))
```

Can any one clarify why I get this type mismatch error and how to get around it?

For your convenience, the interface of scipy.optimize.brute is attached below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The input parameter array is [squeezed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L2535) before it is passed to your function. The 1-D array becomes a 0-D array, basically the value you want to use. Just use your func_cpp without the wrapper.

Also, be aware that slice is defined as slice(start, stop[, step]), you probably meant to switch the 2nd and 3rd argument.

Comment: @w.m. But if I use directly func_cpp without the wrapper, the interactive console gives me     func_cpp(numpy.ndarray)
did not match C++ signature: func(double) where func_cpp is the python function, func is the original c++ function. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, you need to bringt back your wrapper fn and find a way to extract the value from the 0-D array. I'm not sure how to get the exact correct data type for your C++ function, maybe float(arr), or np.float64(arr), or arr.item()?